# Where is the Out Of Bound Multidimensional Array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Getting OBE from MD array. As far as I can see its cumming from the inner loop

```
    int[][] page = new int[3][3];
    int row = -1;
    int column = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
    {
        row++;
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
        column++;
        count++;
        page[row][column] = count;
        }
    }
```

I'm expecting:

```
FirstLoop
row 0 column 1 == 1
row 0 column 2 == 2
row 0 column 3 == 3

SecondLoop
row 1 column 4 == 4
row 1 column 5 == 5
row 1 column 6 == 6


ThirdLoop
row 2 column 7 = 7
row 2 column 8 = 8
row 2 column 9 = 9
```

Got:

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `inner for loop` is incrementing `column`.  You make it through the first run of the `outer loop` just fine.  But on the second iteration of the `outer loop`, `column` hasn't been reset, so you're trying to access index 3, which is out of bounds.

**EDIT:** As is pointed out in a comment, the problem is also because you're starting `column` at `0`, so you'd run out of bounds on the last iteration of the inner loop on the first iteration of the outer loop.  But even if `column` starts at a `-1`, you'd run out of bounds by the first iteration of the inner loop on the second iteration of the outer loop.  Regardless, there is a much less confusing, much more readable way of accomplishing what you're trying to accomplish, as I've demonstrated below.

Reset `column = 0` inside the outerloop, outside the innerloop.

The EASIEST fix, by far, is to just do this:

```
int[][] page = new int[3][3];
int count = 0;

for (int row = 0; row<3; ++row) {
    for (int column = 0; column < 3; ++column) {
        count++;
        page[row][column] = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `column` starts at `0`, unlike `row`, so it is the last iteration of the inner loop, in the first iteration of the outer loop, that fails.

Comment: @afsantos: Quite true. The fundamental point remains, though: Just use `i` and `j`.

Comment: Hmm @afsantos that's true.  But simply changing `column` to start at `-1` still wouldn't completely solve the issue.

Comment: @nhgrif Agreed, it was just a minor detail.

Comment: Yea, I included that in the answer now.

Comment: @nhgrif if you don't mind me saying so. resetting column to 0 in the outter-loop didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Well, your original problem had two potential OBEs.  Read my complete answer as stands... and simply try using the example in my post.

Comment: However I did as suggest use the loops values, I cant remember why I didn't in the first place... I was writing allot then decided to scrap a large chunk of code and just used what was left I think that's how I started with the values outside of the loop. Ether way thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to reset the column var.

Comment: Not quite the problem.

Comment: ok, if I didn't increment row it would start at minus one. so how does that send it into OBE

Answer (score 0):

You're getting OBE on the second iteration, because you have 3 columns, and column variable in being incremented above 3 on the second iteration. Just add column = 0 in the outer loop. You need also to move incrementing column (you can do it in below page[row][column++] = count), because you're incrementing column before using it in the array, hence it will become 4 on all inner loop iteration, giving you another OBE.

```
for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
{
    row++;
    //reset column
    column = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        count++;
        //increment column after it's first use
        page[row][column++] = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's another good point in my original code I did page[row][column] = count; However I was having some issues grabbing data doing it that way. once again I forgot the issue because it was in my last build.